# Remove string unless there is a space

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have this regular expression, I would like it to remove all text between `$` and `$` and replace it with an empty string, UNLESS there is a space anywhere between the two `$` signs, and in that case ignore the replacement. With the regexp that I have now, it removes it no matter if there is a space or not.

```
<?php
$tmp = "<p>
    $random_text$
</p>
<p>
    $random text2$
</p>
<p>
    This is some text
</p>
<p>
    This is some text
</p>";

$tmp = preg_replace("/\\$[^ ].+?\\$/", "", $tmp);
```

So, in the end I would like to have this as the output. As you may notice, the text between the first paragraph tags are gone, but second one still stands.

```
<p>

</p>
<p>
    $random text2$
</p>
<p>
    This is some text
</p>
<p>
    This is some text
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/\\$[^ ]+?\\$/
```

I've just removed the dot

Comment: This will just remove a single non-space character.

Comment: @RyanNaddy only one space is ok?

Comment: 1+, but this seem to cover that.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't thinking earlier. This should work. Though it might be preferable to put `$` in the negative character class as well, to ensure that you are matching consecutive occurrences of `$`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $source = 'His $name$ is $Luis$';
echo $result = preg_replace('/\$(.*?)\$/', '<b>$1</b>', $source);
?>
```